# FASM - Passing a String to a Delphi DLL

Tags: delphi, dll, dllimport, messagebox, fasm

I have a dll coded in Delphi XE2 with the following code:

```
procedure xMain(MSG:String);export;
begin
  MessageBox(0,PWideChar(MSG),'Title',0);
end;

exports xMain;
```

Now, I am importing this function in a FASM application like so:

```
library  dllfile, "testdll.dll"

import   dllfile,\
         xMain,   "xMain"
```

And utilizing is as so:

```
section ".data" data readable writeable

szMSG     db "Message from FASM application!",0

section ".code" code readable executable

invoke    xMain,szMSG
```

But the resulting messagebox appears with distorted characters as so:

[image]

That is the exact result of the function call.

How do I go about solving this issue?

Comment: This error *might* occur because either your DLL or your application uses Unicode encoding to store strings when the other one uses ASCII. I got similar texts often when making the same mistake. This is just a guess though.

Comment: I tried calling MessageBoxW as well instead, same result. I also tried converting the string once passed to the function in the dll to an AnsiString. Still, no luck.

Comment: Josh - You don't address what @beta warns about by using MessageBoxW. (Taking into consideration Jens' answer) if FASM is ansi, use `procedure xMain(MSG:PAnsiChar);export;` and `MessageBoxA`, if it is unicode use `procedure xMain(MSG:PChar);export;` and `MessageBox`. Also specify your calling convention in the export (f.i. stdcall), I don't know how would you do that on FASM side.

Comment: Ya, Tht is what I have done, basically. I stated I tried converting to  Ansi, meaning I used xMain(MSG:PAnsiChar);export; After reading your message I then tried xMain(MSG:PAnsiChar);export;stdcall; which the messagebox now shows up blank....

And shows up the same as in the OP without "stdcall" in the dll.

Comment: @Josh - Maybe you'd like to take chances with other Delphi developers by adding the corresponding tag.

Comment: @JoshLine try including win32w and using "du" in stead of "db" then it should work

Comment: @Josh - I've posted an answer - please see if it's a *working response*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two working samples (using FASM 1.70.03 for Windows):

Ansi version,

dll:

```
library testdll;

uses
  windows;

procedure xMain(MSG: PAnsiChar); export; stdcall;
begin
  MessageBoxA(0, PAnsiChar(MSG), 'Title', 0);
end;

exports xMain;

begin
end.
```

exe:

```
format PE CONSOLE 4.0
entry start

include 'win32a.inc'

section '.code' code readable executable
  start:
    invoke xMain, szMSG
    invoke ExitProcess, 0

section '.data' data readable writeable
    szMSG db 'Message from FASM application!', 0

section '.idata' import data readable writeable
  library kernel32, 'kernel32.dll',\
          dllfile, 'testdll.dll'

  include 'api\kernel32.inc'

  import dllfile,\
         xMain, 'xMain'
```

Unicode version,

dll:

```
library testdll;

uses
  windows;

procedure xMain(MSG: PChar); export; stdcall;
begin
  MessageBox(0, PChar(MSG), 'Title', 0);
end;

exports xMain;

begin
end.
```

exe:

```
format PE CONSOLE 4.0
entry start

include 'win32w.inc'

section '.code' code readable executable
  start:
    invoke xMain, szMSG
    invoke ExitProcess, 0

section '.data' data readable writeable
    szMSG du 'Message from FASM application!', 0

section '.idata' import data readable writeable
  library kernel32, 'kernel32.dll',\
          dllfile, 'testdll.dll'

  include 'api\kernel32.inc'

  import dllfile,\
         xMain, 'xMain'
```

Comment: Very good indeed. For the sake of being explicit, I'd be inclined to use PWideChar. And W versions of API calls. Also, no need for defunct export keyword. +1

Comment: @David - Thanks! I find it quite improbable that none of the comments/answers here help resolve the original issue. I consider this question bogus now, and downvoted as such. It's a pity many people wasted time for such a thing..

Comment: I love that this answer was accepted and awarded bounty. But my answer was declared incorrect despite containing code identical to the ANSI version in this answer.

Comment: @David - The bounty (half of it) was awarded by the *community* according to bounty rules, not by the OP. As for the accept, I would normally guess that, whatever was holding OP back was overcame with only actual compilable code. But I would expect that to happen about a week ago, so I really don't know.. In any case I'm sure that OP does not consider your answer incorrect as I'm nearly sure of that he upvoted both yours and this answer at the time of the accept.

Answer (score 6):

Your output is what happens when you send ANSI text to a function that is expecting UTF-16 encoded text. From which I conclude that your FASM code is sending an ANSI payload to the DLL. And the DLL is compiled in a Unicode aware Delphi for which `string` means `UnicodeString`, `Char` means `WideChar` and so on.

You need to make the two sides match up. For example, by changing the Delphi code:

```
procedure xMain(Msg: PAnsiChar); stdcall;
begin
  MessageBoxA(0, Msg, 'Title', 0);
end;
```

Some other points to note:

1. You don't need `export` on the end of your function declaration. It is ignored by modern Delphi compilers.
2. Don't use Delphi's managed string across module boundaries. In any case on the FASM side you declared the parameter to be a null-terminated pointer to ANSI encoded character array. And that's `PAnsiChar`.
3. Your code uses the Delphi `register` calling convention. It's hard to believe that FASM uses that. I'd expect `stdcall` and Sertac's answer backs that up

Comment: @Sertac It's obviously what's going on. Sometimes it takes an answer with some detail to get the message across.

Comment: Does it not? I can't see any evidence that you have fixed all the problems I raised.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your MSG argument should be a `String` and not a `PChar`?

Comment: I have tried using PChar as well for the param variable type in the dll with no luck. Same result as before.

Comment: PAnsichar, not PChar: The string is stored as 'db' in FASM, rather than 'du'

Comment: @JensBjörnhager Indeed. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.PChar

Comment: I have tried PAnsiChar as well..
I have tried every single data type I could think  of regarding chars/strings....